# winjs windows 10 application taskbar icon

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10, winjs, windows-10-universal

I have a problem with windows taskbar icon/logo size and background. my problem is all windows store app I saw, have smaller icon than normal windows programs. i want to know is there any way to have normal icon for winJS Apps, like other windows programs or microsoft Default Apps

and Is there any way to remove system accent color from background of our app? Without adding full-color image in manifest logo section
as you can see in below image there is huge difference between store Apps *and* microsoft or normal desktop Apps in the taskbar.

if there is no way, I hope microsoft will fix this because, even if we have a good icon this difference between store apps and other apps can effect on our app usage.

[image: image of windows 10 taskbar]

Comment: I don't suppose you're looking for unplated target icon assets? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets#Target-based_assets

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally, I find the complete answer, also many thanks to Tobiah Zarlez.

for have similar Icon to Normal desktop app / and Microsoft apps, like (Mail, Photos, Xbox etc) see following image . . .

[image link of what you should do to have Normal icon in windows 10 store app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/129g0.jpg)

in this process:

1. for taskbar icon go to  "Square 30x30 Logo"
2. you should fill all 8 images section in there.
3. in visual studio open " Solution Explorer "
4. Just change name format of the .targetsize images like this . . .

   Square30x30Logo.targetsize-256.png →→ Square30x30Logo.targetsize-256_altform-unplated.png

do it for all four image have ".targetsize" in "Square 30x30 Logo"

note: don't add "_altform-unplated" for ".scale" images like this one →

Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the automatic padding as part of your app

Look at the "Target-based assets" section of this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets#Target-based_assets

Comment: very thanks, but i still don't get it. how can i have unplated icon ? i change icons in visual studio manifest over and over but it not get similar to other microsoft apps :(
this is image of my visual studio and app taskbar icon
http://www.uplooder.net/img/image/8/37c124b47ac882378da0f6a1184b00d8/windows-taksbar-icon-size.jpg

Comment: You have to have multiple icons for each format, and use a special naming convention as described in that article. Quote from that article (pardon the formatting for comments):

"Target-size list assets without plate

These are assets that don't get plated or scaled by the system.
File name format: *AppList.targetsize-*_altform-unplated.PNG
Impacted apps: Every UWP app
Uses:
Taskbar and taskbar thumbnail (desktop)
Taskbar jumplist
Task view
ALT+TAB"